# How to detect each "this" on click javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to basically detect click event on each card and save this card in a variable but secondGuess is shadowed by firstGuess. What's the solution?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  //ADDING FLIP EFFECT TO EACH CARD
    toggleFlipEffect(cards[i]);
    cards[i].addEventListener("click", compareCards, false);
  }
function compareCards() {
    let points = 0;
    let tries = 0;
    const firstGuess = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt;
    const secondGuess = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt;
    console.log(firstGuess);
    console.log(secondGuess);
    if (firstGuess === secondGuess) {
      points += 1;
      console.log(points);
    } else {
      firstGuess.classList.remove("card--flip");
      secondGuess.classList.remove("card--flip");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (firstGuess === secondGuess) ` it always true .never go to else statement. Because both are same variable .What you trying do with this?.Can you explain and add your markup also.

Comment: @suraj I want to click on the card and store my pick in a variable, then click in another one and do the same thing but It doesn't happen because "this" works only for the first card.

Comment: Use two functions. One to save variables, one to compare them. Within your function which saves the variables, call the compare function only if both variables are assigned.

Comment: @Dragoş And what to do with this variable secondGuess, because It's not being detected at all

Comment: It's not being detected because secondGuess will ALWAYS be equal to firstGuess. You're assigning the same element to both variables.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu Yes that's what I mean. How to change variable secondGuess to make it work?

Comment: Can you put your html + javascript in a fiddle so I can edit?

Comment: And the cards HTML please.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu Yes, here you are:  https://jsfiddle.net/esxp94mc/1/

Comment: @Miqez I've updated the fiddle for you. It works now, but only for the first pair. From here on, you'd need to put the guesses in an array somehow and increment each guess whenever the user correctly guesses each pair. https://jsfiddle.net/esxp94mc/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144118/discussion-between-miqez-and-dragos-paul-marinescu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the HTML and code for *toggleFlipEffect* it is not possible to know how you have implemented the card flipping. In essence you need to act differently to a click on the first card than on the second card. On the first, you really only need to note which card it is. Only when it is the second time, you need to perform the comparison.

Note that when a guess is wrong, you would need to have a delay before concealing those cards again, or else the user would not have the time to see the second card.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
function toggleFlipEffect() {} // mock-up.

var cards = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    //ADDING FLIP EFFECT TO EACH CARD
    toggleFlipEffect(cards[i]);
    // *** add data attribute for quicker access
    cards[i].dataset.value = cards[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt;
    cards[i].addEventListener("click", compareCards, false);
}

// Your variables should not be local to the click event handler:
let points = 0;
let tries = 0;
let revealed = [];

function compareCards() {
    // do not allow more than 2 cards to be revealed in one turn
    if (revealed.length >= 2) return;
    // reveal clicked card
    this.classList.add("card--flip");
    // add it to array with the previous one (if there was one)
    revealed.push(this);
    // Need another card?
    if (revealed.length < 2) return; // allow for second choice
    // We have two revealed cards. Check if they are the same
    if (revealed[0].dataset.value === revealed[1].dataset.value) {
        points += 1; // Yes, keep score
        revealed = []; // initialise for next turn
        score.textContent = points;
    } else {
        // Different: conceal these two cards again, but after a delay
        setTimeout(_ => {
            revealed.forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("card--flip"))
            revealed = []; // initialise for next turn
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
.card--flip {
    background-color: white;
}
div {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/418/418278.svg" alt=1></div>
<div><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/418/418268.svg" alt=2></div>
<div><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/418/418275.svg" alt=3></div><br>
<div><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/418/418268.svg" alt=2></div>
<div><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/418/418278.svg" alt=1></div>
<div><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/418/418275.svg" alt=3></div><br>
score: <span id="score"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear, but I think you need to distinguish between the first and second click on cards. For that, I suggest you to use a global bool variable, initially set to false.

```
var first_click = false;
```

Then, modify your function like this:

```
function compareCards() {
first_click = !first_click;
if (first_click) {
//code you need after first click
} else {
//code you need after second click
}
//code you need to do anyway independently if first or second click.
}
```